# unable to get cell after uicollectioniew reload

Tags: ios, reload, collectionview

I have creating a excel view using collection view. Earlier I was facing an issue while scrolling the collection view listed at :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036224/scrolling-disturbs-layout-of-collectionview
I fixed that issue with the after seeing Shivam's reply in:
[Collection View,with custom layouts, cells misbehave on scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898584/collection-view-with-custom-layouts-cells-misbehave-on-scrolling)

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", @"cCell",indexPath.row];
    [myCollectionView registerClass: [CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID];
    CustomCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
-(void)configureCell:(CustomCell*)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
// configuration code
}
```

I don't know whether it is correct or not, but's its working.But now I am stuck in another problem related to reload of collection view.

**Problem:::**  I have textfield in the cells for which I have implemented textFieldDidEndEditing delegate. I have also provided Next Button which provides proxy navigation to all cells in collection view as desired by me. In the clicked method of next button, I am saving the currentIndexpath, reloading the collection view,  getting the next cell using saved index path, getting the textfield  and making it as first responder. But next textfield never becomes first responder. I debugged the issue and find that after reload I am not able to retrieve the cell. If I remove the reload line then everything works fine.

```
NSIndexPath *reqIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:colId inSection:currentSection];
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:reqIndexPath];
```

Comment: I solved the issue after seeing Lukewar's solution in    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230918/reloading-a-uicollectionview-using-reloaddata-method-returns-immediately-before   Just added [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
after reloadData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this resolved by :

```
   [self.collectionView reloadData];
   [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Thanks to Lukewar reply in 
[Reloading a UICollectionView using reloadData method returns immediately before reloading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230918/reloading-a-uicollectionview-using-reloaddata-method-returns-immediately-before)